# HTTP::Parser::Error with Rails and Twitter Streaming API

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, twitter

I'm currently building an app (Rails 3.1rc6) that involves filtering data from the Twitter Streaming API but am have problems after receiving the stream.

I have tried using both the Twitter-Stream gem and the tweetstream gem but have had the same problem with both, not altogether surprising since tweetstream is dependent on Twitter-Stream.

I can get the stream absolutely fine and print the relevant information with the following code in a tracker.rb file which I am planning on running as a Daemon:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'twitter/json_stream'
require 'json'

EventMachine::run {
  stream = Twitter::JSONStream.connect(
    :path    => '/1/statuses/filter.json?track=rails',
    :auth    => 'user:password'
  )

  stream.each_item do |item|
    @result = JSON.parse(item)
    puts @result["text"]

  end

 #Handle Errors...
```

As am planning to filter certain words and store them in the database but as soon as I try doing anything with ActiveRecord I get the following error

```
Tom-Liveseys-MacBook-Air:twitter_stream Tom$ ruby ./lib/daemons/tracker.rb
String
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/twitter-stream-0.1.14/lib/twitter/json_stream.rb:121:in `<<': Could not parse data entirely            (HTTP::Parser::Error)
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/twitter-stream-0.1.14/lib/twitter/json_stream.rb:121:in `receive_data'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/lib/eventmachine.rb:256:in `run_machine'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/lib/eventmachine.rb:256:in `run'
from ./lib/daemons/tracker.rb:5
```

Does anyone have any idea why I can't do anything useful with the data? I have checked that the JSON is parsed correctly which it is and `@result["text"]` returns the correct string.

Thanks,

Tom

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured out why I was getting the error.  I was trying to grab the tweet `id` as an integer and insert it into a pg database (on heroku) which it didn't like.

Perhaps the error came from trying to READ that property with that big of an integer.  Anyway, I changed the column type to string and grabbed the `tweet["id_str"]` property instead.  Works great now.